Creating and using a central git repository for group access via PyCharm (community ed)
I have been developing small utilities for use in my group via PyCharm, and fumbling my way around git VCS locally.  However, I want/need to create a separate git repo so that others in my group can also put their own work under VCS, as well as participate in and enhance what I'm doing.  As I understand it, this is considered a remote or upstream repo.  I have two main projects, one for the utilities (UTILS_DEV) and one for a library I've turned into an installable package (MY_FUNCTIONSLIB) so that these functions can be used by other programs, and by other people.  They are each stored under /export/dsl/ in separate directories, with their own local git repos.  The /export directory is one which contains user directories, and is mounted to each server in our organization, so data is accessible on all machines.
Based on what Ive been able to find, I installed git on our group's server, created a 'git' user, and cloned one of my existing local project repos into this user's directory (run on the group server):
/home/git/git_repo/:> git clone /export/dsl/UTILS_DEV
This created the UTILS_DEV directory inside of git_repo, and under that what appeared to be the project structure and a .git repo in its subdirectory.  Running git status seems to show it is in order.  I have run chgrp to ensure that the group setting on the git user home and all subdirectories is 'staff' - all user IDs re part of that group.
In PyCharm, though, I seem to be unable to set up the remote repo.  I open the local copy of the project (in /export/dsl/UTILS_DEV), and then go to Define Remotes in the git menu.  I input the name 'origin' and the URL as 'ssh://dsl@group-server/home/git/git_repo/UTILS_DEV'.  It appears to fail - I get returned to the same dialog, but get no error, and it will not save.  I can otherwise ssh to this machine ('ssh dsl@group-server') without error from a PowerShell prompt on my local PC.
The intent was to push the UTILS_DEV project up to the group repo, so that it would be visible to others.  Then I was planning on pushing the MY_FUNCTIONSLIB project to the same repo, as a separate project.  I'm not sure that's the correct thing to do, but I can't even get to the point of making that mistake if I can't connect to the remote server.  What am I missing (either in the specific problem or the general approach)?
CURRENT STATUS (19Sep 13:46 UTC):
Since I am basically running on isolated copied, I deleted the central repo and recreated with gut init --bare.  I then ran git push on each of the local repos.  I see now that to do this I should push to different branches, so I will re-do with that.  Eventually, it looks like this question is simply going to be a write-up of how to accomplish this, so I hope it's useful to someone.

I had to update the problem description (above) as the comment didn't have quite enough room.  Please see CURRENT STATUS.

Did you read the entire message? It says your remote has changes that you don't have locally. You will need to reconcile this.

"The intent was to push the UTILS_DEV project up to the group repo, so that it would be visible to others. Then I was planning on pushing the MY_FUNCTIONSLIB project to the same repo, as a separate project." Due to the way git works, combining two repos into a single repo is not typically done and can be difficult. Each of the original two repos maintains a history of the changes. These two histories are distinct and it is difficult to combine them together. For more details, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

With that said, I recommend creating two separate repos in your central location rather than struggling with combining them.

Thank you for that.  The first link seemed to reference merging two projects into one, which is not what I'm looking for.  The two projects are separate code, and while the utilities do incorporate the library package, the library may well be used in other non-related projects.  As for separate repos - is that what the big boys/girs do?  I would find it difficult to imagine one large merged project for multiple products/libraries, but somehow the idea of separate repos doesn't seem right to me (but I know very little an have no real experience in this).

Git does not have the concept of "projects". It only has repositories. Each repository has a history of changes. Two repositories may share parts of that history or they may have completely disjoin histories. If you created two separate repositories for "utils" and "function library", then they will have completely separate histories and it will be difficult to merge them into a single central repository. Instead, I think that you should push them to two separate central repositories that others can access individually.

"As for separate repos - is that what the big boys/girs do?" It depends. The biggest of the big use what's called a monorepo. However, you probably don't need to do this unless you are at the scale of Google, Facebook, or Amazon. For us lowly small kids that make apps for maybe a few dozen people, separate repos for each library can make sense.

Note that a monorepo isn't necessarily "one large merged project". It could be several separate projects in a single git repository. To emphasize: there is no such thing as a "project" in git. "Project" is usually a concept from your language build chain and your editor, but it isn't a thing in git.

For example, the git repository I interact with for my day job has a .NET solution with multiple projects. The words "solution" and "project" have specific meanings in the .NET world, but again have nothing to do with git. The git repo also has a TypeScript/React project. Multiple projects in a single repo are common, but not necessary. As you get more experience with git, you will figure out what works best for you as far as organizing your projects and repos.

At some point I may find that separate repos for our larger organization better.  At this point I've got them as separate branches in one repo. Feedback from others in the group will be useful, so we'll see.
